# How to extract values from a JSON field with Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

When I run mongdob query I got this json results in a column.
Column name is "user"

```
{"email": "mail1@mail.com"}
{"email": "mail6@mail6.com", "name": "name1"}
{"email": "mail2@mail.com"}
{"email": "mail7@mail7.com", "name": "mail2"}
{"email": "mail3@mail.com"}
{"email": "mail5@mail8.com", "name": "name3"}
{"email": "mail4@mail.com"}
{"email": "mail5@mail9.com", "name": "name4"}
```

However I need to extract email and name from this JSON into different columns like
"email", "name"

How can I do this with Mongodb?

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with aggregate yet?

Following I used `$addField` and `$project`

```
var c = db.getCollection("json_column")
if (c == null) {
    db.createCollection('json_column');
}
db.getCollection("json_column").remove({});

db.getCollection('json_column').insert({user:{"email": "mail6@mail6.com", "name": "name1"}});
db.getCollection('json_column').insert({user:{"email": "mail2@mail.com"}});
db.getCollection('json_column').insert({user:{"email": "mail7@mail7.com", "name": "mail2"}});
db.getCollection('json_column').insert({user:{"email": "mail3@mail.com"}});
db.getCollection('json_column').insert({user:{"email": "mail5@mail8.com", "name": "name3"}});
db.getCollection('json_column').insert({user:{"email": "mail5@mail9.com", "name": "name4"}});

db.getCollection('json_column').aggregate([
{
    $addFields: {
        "email": "$user.email",
        "name": "$user.name"
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        "user":0
    }
}
]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using MongoDB 7.0.1 and Mongosh 2.0.0.
The input JSON example document:

```
let doc = {
  "user": [
    {"email": "mail1@mail.com"},
    {"email": "mail6@mail6.com", "name": "name 1"},
    {"email": "mail2@mail.com"},
    {"email": "mail7@mail7.com", "name": "name 2"},
    {"email": "mail3@mail.com"}
  ]
}
```

Insert into a collection:

```
db.collection.insertOne(doc)
```

Query the collection to get the desired result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$user"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      email: "$user.email",
      name: "$user.name",
    }
  }
])
```

This outputs:

```
[
  { email: 'mail1@mail.com' },
  { email: 'mail6@mail6.com', name: 'name 1' },
  { email: 'mail2@mail.com' },
  { email: 'mail7@mail7.com', name: 'name 2' },
  { email: 'mail3@mail.com' }
]
```